# Problems with calling a Method (Minesweeper)

Tags: java, arrays, methods, javafx, gridpane

I am facing right now a problem where I think that my main is executing a method over and over again, instead of one time. Its better if I explain it according to an example. I already were able to program a Minesweeper game. But i wrote it all in one class MAIN. This time I am trying to do it again but using methods and classes, for the sake of practice and better overview.
As you can see, in my Class Calculations, I am trying to create an Array of Labels. In my Main I am trying to add all the Labels from the Array inside the GridPane. Since it is a minesweeper game, i have to add also random bombs, which will be "X" in my example. I did this little test if it works lbs[10].setText("x"), just to see if it works. It doesnt. It will set the text of ALL labels to X once this method is called! I also want to set an onMouseClicked Event in this class. I would appreciate any help and thank you for your time to read this. I surrounded the codes with Hashtag -> ######

```
//Main
package application;

import...


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            GridPane grid = new GridPane();

            Scene scene = new Scene(grid, (20 * 20), (20 * 20));
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();    

            for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                ColumnConstraints column = new ColumnConstraints(20);
                grid.getColumnConstraints().add(column);
                }

            for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                RowConstraints row = new RowConstraints(20);
                grid.getRowConstraints().add(row);
            }
            //#########################################################
            Calculations c = new Calculations();
            int count = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < c.test().length/20; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < c.test().length/20; y++)
                        {
                          grid.add(c.test()[count], x, y);
                          count++;
                        }
                }
         //#########################################################

               } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    }
```

And here my class "Calculations"

```
package application;

import...

public class Calculations {

    public Label[] test() {

        Label label = new Label();
        Label lbs[] = new Label[20*20];
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 400; i++) {
        lbs[i] = label;
        }

lbs[10].setText("x"); //##### <- doesnt work the way it should be

        return lbs;


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because all the elements in the array `lbs` point to the same Label `label`.

So, when you set the text of any one to `"x"`, it changes the text of `label`, which is, actually, every label.

Change this line, in the loop:

```
lbs[i] = label;
```

to:

```
lbs[i] = new Label();
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! Such a simply mistake made me busy for days! Do u also know how to put an onMouseClicked event there in the class Calculations? I want, lets say, whenever I click on a label that something should happened. lets say the label text will be "X"? I tried many ways. lately i put it inside the For Loop code, but it doesnt work: lbs[i].setOnMouseClicked(e -> { label.setText("X"); });